# How to write a custom Flutter `ImageProvider` to create an `Image` from `Stream<List<int>>`?

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have a function that returns `Stream<List<int>>` representing the image content that I want to display on an `Image` widget.

I know that I can transform this `Stream` into `Uint8List` and send it to the `Image.memory` constructor like this:

```dart
Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(await fileStream.expand((element) => element).toList()));
```

However, using this method, I have to wait until the `Stream` is fully completed in order to display something. Which is not what I want.

My requirement is to display the part of the image that is already loaded and to continue updating the display as more bytes are received. This is something that you can see in web browsers when you open a large image, especially when the internet connection is slow.

How can I implement this using an [`ImageProvider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) in Flutter? I have no idea about how to start. I have read the official documentation but I can't figure it out. Can you point me to a well-detailed tutorial about this topic?